# Where to keep Typescript files in ASP.NET Core

Tags: angular, typescript, gulp, asp.net-core

I've got a Typescript app written in AngularJS 2 on top of ASP.NET Core.  I currently keep my TS files inside of the wwwroot directory.  This works wonderfully well in development.  I'm a little concerned about what happens when I deploy to production.  In production, I'd like to only deploy a minified version of the transpiled typescript files.  I'm sure that I can manage to use gulp to minify them in the wwwroot directory and only deploy the minified versions.  But is this the best practice?

Maybe I should be keeping my Angular app above the wwwroot directory and use gulp to copy what I need down into wwwroot at compile and/or deploy time.  In development, I'd have to copy down the .ts, .js, and .map files for debugging.  It kind of seems like a lot to be doing on compile, and especially if transpiling on save.

Can anyone give some direction on this?

Comment: You probably want to use JSPM beta or Webpack 2.2 rc. Either option adds a fair amount of complexity to your toolchain but you will no longer have this particular problem. The starter setup for Core apps provided by Visual Studio is simply inadequate for all but the simplest apps.

Comment: Also consider splitting your front end into a completely separate project/directory

Comment: @AluanHaddad When I mentioned keeping my TS files inside of the wwwroot directory, they are already in a subdirectory, not in the root.  What would putting the client side stuff in another project buy me?

Comment: Separation of concerns during development. I've just found it easier to write apps that way.

Answer (score 1):

It is not the best way, because having to duplicate your files and depend from a gulp task is not the best thing, but it does the work.

You don't need to serve all the files, my ASP.NET Core Angular2 SPA project was only using the .html and the .js .

I would do as you said, putting my files in another folder (`app` for example), and a gulpfile serving only what I need. Using a `Gulp watcher task`, it will watch and serve only the files that has been modified. This is pretty good for the development process.

For production, you need to bundle your application so that only one file containing everything will be served to your app. I believe you will find tools to do that along with `Gulp`.